# partial match of ingredients (more then one) that return all the foods that contains all of the requested ingredients

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `food` with the following:

```
id name
1  lazania
2  pizza
3  toast
```

I have the table called `ingredients` with the following:

```
id name
1  milk
2  yellow cheese
3  bread
4  ketchup
```

then I have `food_ingredients` table with the following:

```
id food_id ingredient_id
1  1       1
2  1       2
3  2       3
4  2       4
5  3       2
6  3       4
```

of course the ingredients don't really belong to the food... this is just to show what I'm trying to resolve.

now I want the user to be able to search partial match for ingredients that it will return all the food ids that contains all of the searched ingredients

so if the user search for `yellow c, ket` it will show food id `3` because it contains both `yellow cheese` and `ketchup`.

if the user only search for `ketchup` it will return both food id `2` and `3` cause they both contains `ketchup`

if user searches for `milk, bread, ketchup` it will return none cause no food contains all 3 ingredients.

I'm really lost on how to implement such a query, any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I use PostgreSQL version 12.2

thanks

Comment: How does the search input enter your database? Is it a comma-separated string, or an array of strings?

Comment: @Bergi - a comma-separated string

Comment: What if the supplied prefix matches multiple ingredients?

Comment: @jjanes - then they all count... but I guess I should do something like if one if the ingredients contains "" it will be a full match and not partial match, but I guess I can figure this out later so for now they all count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first start with selecting the ingredients from your table that match the search. We split the string using [`string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and use [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html) to compare to their names:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM ingredients i
RIGHT JOIN UNNEST(string_to_array($1, ', ')) AS term ON(i.name LIKE term || '%');
```

Notice that using the join, we can get `NULL`s for search terms that are not even in your ingredients table.

Now, to find the foods that have all these ingredients, we need to do some set logic and can use the [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) and [`EXCEPT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT) operations:

```
SELECT *
FROM food
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT i.id
  FROM ingredients i
  RIGHT JOIN UNNEST(string_to_array($1, ', ')) AS term ON(i.name LIKE term || '%')
EXCEPT
  SELECT ingredient_id
  FROM food_ingredients
  WHERE food_id = food.id
);
```

<sup>([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ba0cd3bb5f546838e9ce0d0d8a6f5bdc))</sup>

Other approaches to find foods that include all the ingredients would be `WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT … food_ingredients WHERE ingredient_id NOT IN (SELECT …))` or `WHERE ARRAY(SELECT … food_ingredients) <@ ARRAY(…)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I get 'syntax error near where' after the 'AS term' changed where to on, still investigating

Comment: @ufk I guess I mismatched my parenthesis. Fixed.

Comment: Oh my, you were right about the missing `ON` clause, I was confusing lateral join and join on syntax. Now tried it myself and made it work :-)

Comment: thank you it works.. I accepted the other answer since performance wise it's faster.

Comment: @ufk Really, is it? What indices do you have? How large are your tables? Can you post an `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220667/discussion-between-ufk-and-bergi).

Comment: @ufk I think what you will need for better query performance is an index on `food_ingredients(ingredients_id)` so that postgres can determine the foods that contain the selected (searched) ingredients faster, and possibly add a condition `AND EXISTS(…)` for foods to contain at least one of the selected ingredients (which is semantically different in case the search is empty, which would select all foods) for higher selectivity. Alternatively try an index on an array.

Answer (score 3):

This is a kind of aggregate problem, where we just need to count the number of input patterns which match the food ingredients.  If we find all N ingredients match a food, that food is contained in the result.

[Complete example of the solution, with data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9c7e31d2ea42b5db813dd93aa2a792f8)

```
WITH inputs (input) AS (
         SELECT 'ye' UNION
         SELECT 'ket'
     )
SELECT f.id, f.name, COUNT(DISTINCT inp.input) AS n
  FROM inputs      AS inp
  JOIN ingredients AS ing
    ON ing.name LIKE inp.input||'%'
  JOIN food_ingredients AS fi
    ON fi.ingredient_id = ing.id
  JOIN food AS f
    ON fi.food_id = f.id
 GROUP BY f.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT inp.input) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inputs)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

To cover your requirement to include all search terms:

```
with invars (search_terms) as (
  values ('yellow c, ket'),
         ('ketchup'),
         ('milk, bread, ketchup')
),
```

Match search terms to existing ingredients and carry an array of `ingredient_id` matching the search terms.

```
search_match as (
  select v.search_terms, i.id as ingredient_id,
         array_agg(i.id) over (partition by v.search_terms) as all_ingredients
    from invars v
   cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(v.search_terms, ', ') as m(term)
    join ingredients i on i.name ~ m.term
),
```

Find `food_id` for foods containing those ingredients

```
match_foods as (
  select distinct s.search_terms, fi.food_id, s.all_ingredients
    from search_match s
    join food_ingredients fi on fi.ingredient_id = s.ingredient_id
)
```

Join back to the `food_ingredient` and `food` tables to find your result.  Keep `food_id` only if it contains all of the `all_ingredients`.

```
select m.search_terms, m.food_id, f.name
  from match_foods m
       join food_ingredients fi on fi.food_id = m.food_id
       join food f on f.id = m.food_id
 group by m.search_terms, m.food_id, f.name, m.all_ingredients
having array_agg(fi.ingredient_id) @> m.all_ingredients;
```

Results:

```
| search_terms  | food_id | name  |
| ------------- | ------- | ----- |
| ketchup       | 2       | pizza |
| ketchup       | 3       | toast |
| yellow c, ket | 3       | toast |
```

[Working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jDKyS3P6VXJahkqq8Jo9QD/0)